# Python script called by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I want to call a python script using javascript (AJAX). I think this is working (I don't get any errors).

This is my ajax and html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>


<table id="table">
   <tr>
       <td id="col1">
           <form>

               <p><label for="text"> your text</label>:<input type="text" id="text"></input></p>

               <input type="button" value="tester" onclick="addImage()" />
           </form>
       </td>
       <td id = "img"></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<p id="result"></p>



<script>
function callPy(data1, data2){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"pythonTest.py",
        data:{data1: data1, data2:data2},
        success: callbackFunc
    });
}
function callbackFunc(response) {
    $('#result').html('<li>'+response.x+'</li>');
}
function addImage(){
    callPy(1,2);    
}
</script>
```

This is the result of  `callbackFunc`: undefined

So I think Python script don't detect `data1` and `data2` But I don't know how to get `data1` and `data2` in the python script ...

This is my python script :

```
import csv
from numpy import genfromtxt
from numpy import matrix

def main(data1, data2):
    x = data1 + data2
    return x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x=main()
    return x;
```

Comment: You can't just call script from javascript. You need some web-server that can accept your ajax request, call your script and response back to javascript.

Comment: Is there an other way to do this?

Comment: @wxcvbn No, there is no other way to do that. JavaScript interacts with other scripts (or programs) via network and http servers.

Comment: What your python scripts does you could do in JavaScript, if its going to be something you need to do in python you will need to set up a server. There are a couple of light weight python frameworks that you could use, that might help like **flask** or **bottle**